# Cosmos db data retrieval using Node JS

Tags: node.js, sql-server, azure-cosmosdb

I am retrieving data from Cosmos DB based on one of SQL Server 2019 based table column in Node JS code.

`mssqldate` is defined as `datetime` type and doing type casting while filtering it.

Still data is not getting retrieved.

Anyone faced similar situation or any other way to achieve it.

Code:

```
const cosmosClient = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, key });
const container = cosmosClient.database(databaseId).container(collectionId);

const query = 'SELECT c.name,c.age FROM emp c WHERE c.last_update_date >  DateTimeToTimestamp(@mssqldate)';
const { resources } = await container.items.query(query,
{ parameters:  [
        { 
            name: '@mssqldate', 
            value: mssqldate 
          }
          ] 
}).fetchAll();
```

1. I tried hardcoding `@mssqldate` value, data is coming but coming dynamic thing not working.
2. Made `mssqldatetime` column as `datetime2` datatype.

I want to compare day, month, year and time (all values from cosmos db date) and data should get retrieved from `emp` table.

Comment: So what is `mssqldate` actually and exactly? As per the [`DateTimeToTimestamp()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/datetimetotimestamp), _This function returns `undefined` if the date and time isn't a valid ISO 8601 date and time string._

Comment: mssql date is in datetime format . 
2023-10-01 10:10:30

Comment: If that's the format you're using then it's not the required format: _A Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) date and time **string** in the ISO 8601 format `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.fffffffZ`._ Amongst other things the `T` is relevant.

Comment: Please edit to show actual data, along with any other pertinent details. As written, there’s no way to know what your date properties look like in Cosmos DB and why you’re not matching anything. Cosmos DB doesn’t have a built-in date type so it’s just a string (or maybe clock ticks, or however else you chose to store your dates)

Comment: Thanks David , by changing data type of mssql table column to varchar , issue is fixed . I am able to retrieve data now . Thanks for quick help .. Really appreciated.

Comment: Changing the column datatype to `varchar` in SQL Server is not the correct solution. You should be storing it as `datetime2` there and converting it to the desired string representation for Cosmos either in the `SELECT` statement or in the application